# Find min(max) value amoung all object.properties and return result as object or (modify original object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, design-patterns

This a bit easy task at first look, with finding the min/max values in Object, has become a challenge for me.

I have the following object (with 3 fixed keys):

```
let object_ = {
    vendor: 5, //(Number),
    market: 2, //(Number)
    derivative: {
        price: 15 //(Number)
    }
}
```

And I am trying to find not just the min/max value, but return it as an object / modify the original one, which should looks like that:

result for `min`: //as an object

```
{ market: 2}
```

result for `max`: //as an object

```
derivative: {
    price: 15 //(Number)
}
```

As for now, I have the following code which solves this problem by creating an Array from original object's properties (by manually checking each property's name), like:

```
/** Create an array of objects from object_*/

let array = [
   {market: 2},
   {vendor: 5},
   {derivative: 15}
]

/** Find the necessary values in array with map and reduce*/
```

And then finding min/max values from all objects inside array, but the problem is that I should convert result of my code back to the original schema like:

```
if (resultObject.property === 'derivative') {
   resultObject.derivative = {
      price: resultObject.derivative  //15
   }
}
```

So the question is:

> Am I on the right path, should I create an `Array of objects` for this case? Cause it's important for me, return not just the number itself, but with a custom named property.

Maybe someone has more better/shorter solution with ES6 syntax or modifying the original object with `delete` not `min (or max)` properties. Or can point me a way in to it?

Comment: Hello, @NinaScholz. Sorry, I mean, I should find min/max values across all properties of the object. So I just corrected the question's title/description.

Comment: from all of the properties of `object_` (vendor, market, derivative). The challenge is, that `derivative` property isn't a `Number,` it's an other object with it's own fields, and only one field named `price` in it have the necessary `Number` value to compare with `market` and ` vendor` And I should return some-kind of `pointer` which shows that lowest/highest value is stored in a certain property

Comment: what should happen if more than one property is min or max?

Comment: you mean, if `{vendor: 1}` and `{market: 1}` also? Tbh I haven't thought about it. In my own case there is a strong hierarchy between them. `vendor` is the "heaviest", and `derivative` has "lowest priority". Untill you asked I'll never thought about it, so I should add this to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the value and path to it, select min and max value and rebuild objects for min and max.

This approach works only for a single min and max values.

```js
const
    getValues = object => {
        return Object
            .entries(object)
            .flatMap(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
                ? getValues(v).map(([keys, v]) => [[k, ...keys], v])
                : [[[k], v]]
            );
    },
    setValue = (target, [keys, value]) => {
        const last = keys.pop();
        keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, target)[last] = value;
        return target;
    },
    getMinMax = object => {
        const
            [min, max] = getValues(object)
                .reduce((r, v, i) => {
                    if (!i) return [v, v];
                    if (v[1] < r[0][1]) r[0] = v;
                    if (v[1] > r[1][1]) r[1] = v;
                    return r;
                }, [])
                .map(v => setValue({}, v));
        return { min, max };
    },
    object = { vendor: 5, market: 2, derivative: { price: 15 } },
    result = getMinMax(object);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

At the start of the function set min index to 0. Then loop through every key in the object from index 1. Test if the value at the key is an object, and if it is call the current function for it, and set the value to the returned value.Then test if the value is less then one at the index. If it is set index to i. At the end return an object with the value.

```
function getMin(obj) {
    let minIndex = 0;
    let keys = Object.keys(obj); //Get all the keys in the object
    for(let i = 0;i < keys.length;i++) { // Loop through the keys
        let value = obj[keys[i]];
        if(typeof value !== 'number') { // If it's not a number get the minimum value in the object
            value = getMin(value);
        }
        if(value < obj[keys[minIndex]]) minIndex = i; //If the value is less than the value at the min index, set the min index to the current index
        // You can just change the sign to greater for the max function
    }
    let returnObject = {};
    returnObject[keys[minIndex]] = obj[keys[minIndex]]; // Sets the object so it doesn't only return the value
    return returnObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution that I am using right now. It does the job well, but it's a bit monstrous I guess. So I won't accept it as an answer on my own question. But it still an option anyway.

```
let object = {
    market: 5,
    vendor: 2,
    derivative: {
        price: 15
    }
};

let bufferArray = [];

for (const property in object) {
    if (typeof object[property] === 'object') {
        bufferArray.push({name: property, value: object[property].price});
    } else {
        bufferArray.push({name: property, value: object[property]});
    }
}

let {name, value} = bufferArray.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.value < curr.value ? prev : curr); //just change < to > for max value
let newObject = {[name]: value};
console.log(newObject); //{ vendor: 2 }
```